# Backup Android Google maps api v1 key

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I backup my google maps api key? I can no longer request a new key as Google stop supporting v1. I need it for 2 more weeks to finish my thesis in case of reinstalling my Windows.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, don't you have it in text form in your source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do can do that any way you like. Just save the value of android:apiKey="0xGmDe0ExclMuFz.......vYXDnVQ" to a file or mail yourself. Remember to also backup your keystore. If you are using debug keystore it is stored in `~/.android/debug.keystore`.

Comment: And after reinstalling windows I can copy debug.keystore file in the correct path and import the project right?

Comment: Yes. Try to copy to some other machine before reinstalling your system. Safer this way in case random guy from internet forgot something.